# Get different dimensions from image URLs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some questions related to image URLs.

More specifically, some image links in websites have a specific behaviour depending on the link changes you make.

For example :

**a) The image is actively cropped by a number in the link :**

http://lbnewsng.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Hamilton21080-1080x352.jpg

If you remove the 1080x352 part from the link above, then we are getting the full size of the image

http://lbnewsng.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Hamilton21080.jpg

**b) The image size is dynamic depending on the URL values :**

http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/622/992/hi-res-c80ddee0a4069c9e79670c8d26e65173_crop_exact.jpg?h=310&w=527&q=70

If you put excessive numbers for the dimension in the last part of the URL above, then we are getting the original dimensions of the image :

http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/003/622/992/hi-res-c80ddee0a4069c9e79670c8d26e65173_crop_exact.jpg?h=6310&w=6527&q=670

For this particular link, in the past, I was able to get the original dimension by just deleting the part after the "?" and substituting the "crop_exact" part with "original". It was a crazy thought I had and it worked.

**c) The image size is dynamic. There is a value limit for the dimensions :**

The original link is here :

http://images.adrivo.com/images/224/150/0651722.jpg

I had the idea of changing the "224/150" part to another one. I noticed that I was getting the same image in different dimensions. I tested it and found out that the biggest value I could put there was "1440"

http://images.adrivo.com/images/1440/0651722.jpg

I wonder how the URLs are interactive. The user can change some things and get different results (dimensions of the image). I want to find more about this as I am a huge collector of photos. Is that something that is being controlled by JavaScript? I am guessing in some Wordpress templates, it is really easy to change the URLs in a specific way to get the original dimensions of an image.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Information Security! I don't think this has much to do with the topic of the site, so it will likely be closed. But I can tell you that it is not JavaScript. The server gets the URL, and is programmed to behave differently depending on the values. It can be e.g. a PHP script that reads the URL parameters and resize the image based on them. There is no standard for how the URL is translated to image dimensions, but there are many web application that offers this kind of functionality to reduce network load by not sending unecessarily large images.

Comment: @Anders Thanks. Where is the best site to post this question? I mean in stack exchange. I saw relevant topics here in IT.

Comment: The question is off-topic but: It is perfectly normal that users get a different result if they change something on the URL. Examples are not only different image resolutions but different content language and even different content. And of course 404 errors.  At least the part up to the '#' is fully handled on the server, i.e. not Javascript involved.

Comment: I would like to move this topic to the relevant stackexchange site :)

Comment: I'll migrate it over to SU for you.

Answer (score 0):

a) Both images exist in the server statically(full image and thumbnail). There is no way to obtain intermediate values.

b) and c) The image is served dynamically cropped using **PHP**. In the server only exists the full size image only and the parameters in the URL define which size is showed to the user.